# how to use ajax for django login

Tags: ajax, django

I want to create a ajax login that sends data and renders the html without refreshing the page here.

I followed some of the already answered solutions here,

but it's throwing me a 400 error.

how do i solve the error, and have the login info such as username displayed in the designated layer (.login_div)?

could you help me out?

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/normalize.css" %}' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/skeleton.css" %}' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/index.css" %}' />

</head>



<body>
  <script src='{% static "js/jquery.js" %}'></script>

  <div class="login_div"></div>
<form id="login_form" method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address
            </label>
            <input name="username">
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Password
            </label>
            <input name="password">
          </div>

          <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>

          <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>

          </form>

          <script>
            $('form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault()
                $.ajax({
                  type:"POST",
                  url: '../login/',
                  data: $('#login_form').serialize(),
                  success: function(response){
                    $('.login_div').text(username)
                  // do something with response
                  response['result']; // equals 'Success or failed';
                  response['message'] // equals 'you"re logged in or You messed up';
               }
              });
            });
          </script>


</body>
</html>
```

and views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
import json

def ajax_login(request):
    print(request.method)
    print(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username', '').strip()
        password = request.POST.get('password', '').strip()
        print("U: %r / P: %r" % (username, password))
        if username and password:
            # Test username/password combination
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            # Found a match
            if user is not None:
                # User is active
                if user.is_active:
                    # Officially log the user in
                    login(self.request, user)
                    data = {'success': True}
                else:
                    data = {'success': False, 'error': 'User is not active'}
            else:
                data = {'success': False, 'error': 'Wrong username and/or password'}

            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')

    # Request method is not POST or one of username or password is missing
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()


def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

Comment: your URL should be an absolute path, not relative. Just use the same url generated by `{% url 'login' %}` instead of `../login/`

Comment: okay, now im getting "the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" error.

Comment: Good. now you can inspect the server logs or the console and figure out what is going on

Comment: My guess for the 500 is, `self.request` should be just `request` - looks like you copy pasted the code from some class based view.

Comment: umm. i fixed the codes but im still getting the following errors. any idea?

Comment: jquery.js:4 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/ 400 (Bad Request)send @ jquery.js:4ajax @ jquery.js:4(anonymous function) @ (index):74dispatch @ jquery.js:3q.handle @ jquery.js:3
(index):79 Uncaught ReferenceError: username is not defined

Comment: well.. the error message says it all. you havent defined username

Comment: yes. but first, i have no idea why im getting 400 error, there's nothing that seems wrong.. and i also do not know how to define username in the script... :p could you help me out a little?

Comment: Are you getting 400 error after submitting login form(POST)? or while rendering login page(GET)?

Comment: @MicroPyramid i don't know how i fixed the error, but now that i added csrf token both to the html and jquery script, it seems to be working.